# SQLite: Why can't parameters be used to set an identifier?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm refactoring a little [side project](https://jrsmith3.github.io/analyzing-sugar-content-of-my-favorite-fast-food-places.html) to use SQLite instead of a python data structure so that I can learn SQLite. The data structure I've been using is a list of dicts, where each dict's keys represent a menu item's properties. Ultimately, these keys should become columns in an SQLite table.

I first thought that I could create the table programmatically by creating a single-column table, iterating over the list of dictionary keys, and executing an `ALTER TABLE`, `ADD COLUMN` command like so:

```python
# Various import statements and initializations

conn = sqlite3.connect(database_filename)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE menu_items (item_id text)")

# Here's the problem:
cursor.executemany("ALTER TABLE menu_items ADD COLUMN ? ?", [(key, type(value)) for key, value in menu_data[0].iteritems()])
```

After some more reading, I realized parameters cannot be used for identifiers, only for literal values. The [PyMOTW on `sqlite3`](https://pymotw.com/2/sqlite3/index.html#using-variables-with-queries) says

> Query parameters can be used with **select**, **insert**, and **update** statements. They can appear in any part of the query where a literal value is legal.

Kreibich says on p. 135 of *Using SQLite* (ISBN 9780596521189):

> Note, however, that parameters can only be used to replace literal
>   values, such as quoted strings or numeric values. Parameters
>   cannot be used in place of identifiers, such as table names or
>   column names. The following bit of SQL is invalid:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM ?; -- INCORRECT: Cannot use a parameter as an identifier
> ```

I accept that positional or named parameters cannot be used in this way. Why can't they? Is there some general principle I'm missing?

Similar SO question:

- [Python sqlite3 string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114819/python-sqlite3-string-formatting)

Comment: You might find https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html of interest and consider how changing a column name affects whether an index can be used and therefore the nature of the compiled bytecode.

Answer (score 5):

Identifiers are syntactically significant while variable values are not.

Identifiers need to be known at SQL compilation phase so that the compiled internal bytecode representation knows about the relevant tables, columns, indices and so on. Just changing one identifier in the SQL could result in a syntax error, or at least a completely different kind of bytecode program.

Literal values can be bound at runtime. Variables behave essentially the same in a compiled SQL program regardless of the values bound in them.

Comment: I knew the basic answer, but I had no idea how to put it into words...  your explanation is a keeper -- thanks!  It should be noted that the question and your answer transcend SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but every database I ever used has the same limitation.

I think it would be analogous to use a variable to hold the **name** of another variable. Most languages do not allow that, PHP being the only exception I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the technical reasons, dynamically choosing table/column names in SQL queries is a design smell, which is why most databases do not support it.

Think about it; if you were coding a menu in Python, would you dynamically create a class for each combination of menu items? Of course not; you'd have one Menu class that contains a list of menu items. It's similar in SQL too.

Most of the time, when people ask about dynamically choosing table names, it's because they've split up their data into different tables, like `collection1`, `collection2`, ... and use the name to select which collection to query from. This isn't a very good design; it requires the service to repeat the schema for each table, including indexes, constraints, permissions, etc, and also makes altering the schema harder (Need to add a field? Now you need to do it across hundreds of tables instead of one).

The correct way of designing the database would be to have a single `collection` table and add a `collection_id` column; instead of querying `collection4`, you'd add a `WHERE collection_id = 4` constraint to your `SELECT` queries. Note that the `4` is now a value, and can be replaced with a query parameter.

For your case, I would use this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE menu_items (
    item_id TEXT,
    key TEXT,
    value NONE,
    PRIMARY KEY(item_id, key)
);
```

Use `executemany` to insert a row for each entry in the dictionary. When you need to load the dictionary, run a `SELECT` filtering on `item_id` and recreate the dictionary one row/entry at a time.

(Of course, as with everything in Software Engineering, there are exception. Tools that operate on schemas generically, such as ORMs, will need to specify table/column names dynamically.)